# Cannot load or view photos in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, photos

My iPhone Photos indexes seem to be corrupted. I can’t go into Photos to view my existing photos or videos. It either crashes when I try to open it or shows me a blank screen. When I try to use an app to open a photo it freezes.

When I go to Setting>General>About it show that my Videos and Photos as 0 (zero).

I am running iOS 13.5.1. I have 8gb diskspace left out of 256gb.

The problem started when my iPhone was running out of diskspace. I started to delete heaps of images and videos. After some time my iPhone started to behave strangely. My clock app disappeared. All the name of my home apps disappeared. I decided to do a All Reset Settings. I forgotten to do a backup.

On boot up, the load bar freezes. I attempted to install many times until I finally was able to get iTune to connect and update the OS to the latest.

I can now access all my apps but not my photos.

I appreciate any advice or suggestions as I couldn’t find any using Google. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the photos elsewhere? usually an issue like this resolves by backing up the phone to your computer, wiping it and then restoring from backup. But if you don't already have the photos elsewhere this could erase all of them assuming they are not gone already.

Comment: I have over a year of photos not back up. I have tried to use some software like PhoneRescue and it was unable to detect any photos in the phone. Not looking good.